Script to get information about author of the last modified of a Google sheet cell
I want to get a formula or script to get information about the author of the last cell modified in Google sheet

I want to expecting Danil Pobirsky but i can't
I used Apps Scripts
function getCreator(row) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getMaxColumns());
  var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
  return cell.getValue();
}

